# cookie_serializer in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

Upgrading to Rails 7 and going through `new_framework_defaults_7.0.rb` and not understanding in `Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :json` and "# If you have configured the serializer elsewhere, you can remove this."

Does the statement mean I can remove config/cookies_serializer.rb`or the line in`new_framework_defaults_7.0.rb`. I assume it needs to be set somewhere, but not twice.

Comment: In Rails 7, the default serializer is JSON. So if you don't override it anywhere (you kill every reference) it will default to :json. If you want to have something else, you need to keep it in an intializer and use another value (such as :marshall). So basically if you are happy with the :json serializer, you can delete it everywhere.

Comment: Of course, provided you set defaults to Rails 7 in your config/application.rb file . If you are transitionning you may want to use this `Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer = :json` and incrementally turn them on while still using Rails 6 defaults. This allows to transition from 6 to 7 smoothly.

Comment: @Maxence Thank you. Turns out I do need it and decided to keep the separate file `config/cookies_serializer.rb` with `:hybrid` as the option. Seems a little odd to keep a separate file but I guess I makes upgrades easier. Actually I just figured out that's probably why separate files.